# how to hide second and millisecond from jquery ui datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I use jquery-datetimepicker in this [link](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker) 
my simple code like this `$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();`

but the GUI appear like this

[image]

I want date calender and time by (Hours and Minutes) only appear in the widget 
I trying this code but no effects.

```
$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
showTimePicker: false, 
showSecond:false,
showMillisec:false,
showMicrosec:false,
showTimezone:false
});
```

Comment: I tried it on JSFiddle.
Don't be scared it's without CSS. But as you can see it works fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/ujz4gt95/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the problem is  jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css file not loaded correctly

it was like this

`<link href='datetimepicker/src/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css'/>`

I forgot to add link type

`<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='datetimepicker/src/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css' />`

it's working now .
@zedd thank you very much . you put my hand in the problem point

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that a *null* value for *showMillisec* and micro will auto detect the controls from timeFormat, so try to set them to null, or not setting them at all

> The default of null will use detection from timeFormat.

Comment: maybe the control shows/hides parts using css, and your black theme maybe has css that overrides this?